# Convert data frame columns to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have large Pandas dataframes looking something like this:

```
  Label1 Label2 Label3   Id1  Val1   Id2  Val2   Id3  Val3
0      A      B      C     a  0.80     b  0.79     c  0.29
1      A      B      D  None   NaN  None   NaN     e  0.06
2      E      B      F  None   NaN     b  0.86  None   NaN
3      E      G      H     b  0.16  None   NaN     f  0.34
```

I'd like to convert the columns fron Id1 onwards to a dictionary like so:

```
  Label1 Label2 Label3                               kvp
0      A      B      C  {'a': 0.8, 'b': 0.79, 'c': 0.29}
1      A      B      D                       {'e': 0.06}
2      E      B      F                       {'b': 0.86}
3      E      G      H            {'b': 0.16, 'f': 0.34}
```

Is there an Pandas idiom for this kind of selection and transformation or do I have to write code to iterate through the rows?

Comment: what have you tried ? Load the lines, split by tab, grab the first 4 items, group the other 2 by 2 and use that as a dict constructor ?

Comment: Your Ids don't quite match up with your dict - is Id2 in row 0 meant to be 'b' (rather than 'a'), and Id3 'c' (rather than 'b')?

Comment: @Bruce the table in the question isn't from a text file, it's the standard printout of a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe (ie, it doesn't need parsing like that).

Comment: thx, missed this panda tag (and the question might have been more ambiguous at that time). I'm good with python, never heard about black and white bears :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the dictionary for a single row by taking the relevant columns, reshaping them into a 2-column numpy array and then turning that into a dict:

```
>>> a
  Label1 Label2 Label3   Id1  Val1   Id2  Val2   Id3  Val3
0      A      B      C     a  0.80     b  0.79     c  0.29
1      A      B      D  None   NaN  None   NaN     e  0.06
2      E      B      F  None   NaN     b  0.86  None   NaN
3      E      G      H     b  0.16  None   NaN     f  0.34

>>> a.irow(0)[3:].reshape(3,2)
array([['a', 0.80000000000000004],
       ['b', 0.79000000000000004],
       ['c', 0.28999999999999998]], dtype=object)
>>> dict(_)
{'b': 0.79000000000000004, 'c': 0.28999999999999998, 'a': 0.80000000000000004}
```

You can write a function that uses that principle to create the new row from the old one:

```
def adjust_row(row):
    kvp_data = row[3:].valid()
    kvp_data = kvp_data.reshape(kvp_data.size//2, 2)
    kvp = dict(kvp_data)
    return row[:3].append(pd.Series({'kvp': kvp}))
```

Note that this excludes the `None`s and `NaN`s with the call to `valid()`, and *calculates* the appropriate number of rows for the temporary numpy array. Verify that it does the right thing for any given row:

```
>>> adjust_row(a.irow(1))
Label1              A
Label2              B
Label3              D
kvp       {'e': 0.06}
dtype: object
```

Once you have that, you can apply it to every row using the `apply` method on dataframes:

```
>>> a.apply(adjust_row, axis=1)
  Label1 Label2 Label3                               kvp
0      A      B      C  {'b': 0.79, 'c': 0.29, 'a': 0.8}
1      A      B      D                       {'e': 0.06}
2      E      B      F                       {'b': 0.86}
3      E      G      H            {'f': 0.34, 'b': 0.16}
```